# How can I style stripe credit card fields?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, stripe-payments, styling

I've been integrating stripe using this html coden bootstrap 4.

```
<div class="form-control" id="card-element"></div>
```

which gives me the following output

[image]

However, I want to have this design:

[image]

The JavaScript part is as usual:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

<script>
.......
.......
      stripe = Stripe(publishableKey);
      var elements = stripe.elements();
      var style = {
        base: {
          color: "#32325d",
          fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
          fontSmoothing: "antialiased",
          fontSize: "16px",
          "::placeholder": {
            color: "#aab7c4"
          }
        },
        invalid: {
          color: "#fa755a",
          iconColor: "#fa755a"
        }
      };
      var card = elements.create("card", {hidePostalCode: true, style: style });
      card.mount("#card-element");
.......
.......
</script>
```

How can I obtain the second design in which each field is separated?

Answer (score 2):

Card Elements supports splitting into different fields. See [Stripe Elements Examples](https://stripe.dev/elements-examples/) page, click on "View Source on Github". For example they use individual `cardNumber`, `cardExpiry`, and `cardCvc` Elements with a custom web font.

Comment: This is a good resource. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Stripe card is an additional code that will be added to page by javascript. Its not correct to manipulate rendered attributes after they rendered but you can force change them by global css.
for preventing the effect on other elements you can put a class name above the place the card will render and start your css selector by that class name.